# I want to check information contained in a Google sheet, as the respondent is completing a form

Tags: google-sheets

We are using forms to allow people (staff) to book equipment out of a store, self service. We record who took what, and when they book it back in. They are asked if the tool condition is good, and if not, are taken to another part of the form to select a fault category. I record this information in the linked sheet.

so my question is can I read the information in the "fault" column of the linked sheet for that item ID, and generate a message to the form user such as "This item has been reported as faulty - please do not use it!" etc etc

If I could script the form so that it scans the linked sheet in the relevant column / row for the item they are trying to scan out, and then warn them that is has an entry in the "Fault" column, that would be perfect. Ideally as they scan the barcode of the item they are taking, before submitting the form, but after submit would be fine too.

I have searched widely and not yet found a solution

Comment: Welcome to [so]. On  this site questions should be straight to the point and include a brief description of the search/research efforts made by the OP (ref. [ask]). Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Hey there @Scott, can you please share the code you have used and a more accurate description of what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi and thanks for replying. I have searched for a way to look up information in the linked sheet, as the respondent is entering data in the form, but there seems no obvious answer in the Google API for this, I guess it is not meant to be used that way but I can't even seem to add a script to the form, only the sheet itself. Maybe this is not possible but a lot of people seem to ask the same question online with no resolution.

Comment: I am trying to read data from a linked sheet, using the form linked to that sheet. I want to search a column for a certain value while the user is filling in the form.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by "I have searched for a way to look up information in the linked sheet, as the respondent is entering data in the form". Which linked sheet? What is the "fault" column? Can you please update your question and include all the details for this? Also, a **sanitized copy of your sheet** will be of great help along with the solutions **you have tried**. Cheers! @Someone

Comment: Ok, I have a sheet example - people use a form I created to indicate their own user ID and the Tool ID of a piece of equipment they want to take out. If the equipment has already been marked as faulty by a previous user, I want to warn them as they enter the tool ID in the google form field.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rVumNRdxyYS_Ghn2yZb-YbQB4tlpic7iBAeDbdvEfAY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: All google forms have a linked sheet, into which the data entered into the form, is stored, I want to be able to look up previously entered data in the sheet, from the form as a new submission is being made. Its not as complicated a question as it seems to be perceived, even if the answer would be complex or even impossible.

Comment: Can you please share the code you have used? @Scott

Comment: Hi, I have not found any code yet, I was looking to see if anyone knew a method to be able to read a cell in the sheet linked to the google form, from the form itself, and display a message box to the user of the form. Is it possible to put javascript in the google form itself basically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the only triggers which are available for Forms are the `onOpen`, `onInstall` and `onFormSubmit`, this cannot be done directly.

#### Possible solutions

**1. You can develop your own form**

This can be done by using Apps Script & HTML & JavaScript and creating your own *Sheets add-on* which will interract with the sheet you have in order to check the status of the tool.

**2. You can programmatically update either the question name or the form description in order to include the accepted values for the question regarding the tools.**

This can be done by creating a **script attached to the sheet** and using the `onEdit()`. So whenever a change is made in the tools section for example, this new data can be gathered as a string and update the fields to contain the updated values for the tools.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers);
- [Extending G Suite with Add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/overview).